# How do I strip data from a row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe and I need to strip out components.schema.Person.properties and just call it id.

| column | data_type | data_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| components.schemas.Person.properties.id | string | Unique Mongo Id generated for the person. |

Comment: `df['column'].str.split('.').str[-1]` ..?

Comment: `df['column'].str.replace('components.schemas.Person.properties.', '')`.

Comment: ah, yes, Thanks.

Comment: df['column'].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1] ..

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
```

or more compact [solution by @Chris Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69771753/how-do-i-strip-data-from-a-row-in-pandas#comment123329869_69771753):

```py
df['column'].str.split('.').str[-1]
```